# Mobile Responsive Divs

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have created 3 divs that line side-by-side on 1 row on desktop view but I would like each div to stack vertically on mobile devices only. I can't seem to figure out the correct CSS code/media query for this.

This is the HTML div code I'm using in the body of the post:

```
  <div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 5px;">
    SOURCE 1
    <div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 5px;">
    SOURCE 2
    <div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 5px;">
    SOURCE 3
```

Here is the full HTML code--I am embedding 3 Instagram photos.

```
   div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 3px;">

    blockquote class="instagram-media" style="background: #FFF; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; padding: 0; width: calc(100% - 2px);" data-instgrm-captioned="" data-instgrm-version="6">

    div style="padding: 1px;">

    div style="background: #F8F8F8; line-height: 0; margin-top: 40px; padding: 50.0% 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;"></div>

    a style="color: #000; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 17px; text-decoration: none; word-wrap: break-word;" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BC2kmbmhTOY/" target="_blank">#CherryBlossom #Doughnuts: Vanilla Cream Cheese Glaze w/ a #Cherry Filling, and featuring a #CherryBlossomTree design made with Chocolate (tree) and Cherry Buttercream Flowers Available Soon! March 15 to April 17.</a>

    A photo posted by Astro Doughnuts (@astrodoughnuts) on <time style="font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px;" datetime="2016-03-12T12:17:51+00:00">Mar 12, 2016 at 4:17am PST</time>

    /div></blockquote>

    script src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js" async="" defer="defer">

    /script>

    /div>

    div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 3px;">

    blockquote class="instagram-media" style="background: #FFF; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; padding: 0; width: calc(100% - 2px);" data-instgrm-captioned="" data-instgrm-version="6">

    div style="padding: 1px;">

    div style="background: #F8F8F8; line-height: 0; margin-top: 40px; padding: 50.0% 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;"></div>

    a style="color: #000; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 17px; text-decoration: none; word-wrap: break-word;" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCq4otrp-ZW/" target="_blank">Spring truly arrives when flowers start blooming, and our #CherryBlossom macaron has certainly begun showing its petals! Sweet and subtle, it's the perfect spring bite. #oliviamacaron #frenchmacarons #springtime #GeorgetownDC #ShopTysons #DCeats</a>

A photo posted by Olivia Macaron (@oliviamacaron) on <time style="font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px;" datetime="2016-03-07T23:22:02+00:00">Mar 7, 2016 at 3:22pm PST</time>

/div>

/blockquote>

script src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js" async="" defer="defer">

/script>

/div>

div style="float: left; width: 30%; margin-left: 3x;">

blockquote class="instagram-media" style="background: #FFF; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; padding: 0; width: calc(100% - 2px);" data-instgrm-captioned="" data-instgrm-version="6">

div style="padding: 1px;">

div style="background: #F8F8F8; line-height: 0; margin-top: 40px; padding: 50.0% 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;"></div>

a style="color: #000; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 17px; text-decoration: none; word-wrap: break-word;" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BDJCBpnAi8f/" target="_blank"> Happy Saturday! </a>

A photo posted by Georgetown Cupcake (@georgetowncupcake) on <time style="font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px;" datetime="2016-03-19T16:21:18+00:00">Mar 19, 2016 at 9:21am PDT</time>

/div>

/blockquote>

script src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js" async="" defer="defer">

/script>

/div>

div style="clear: both; height: 1em;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add your actual HTML and the CSS you have tried? I'm assuming you do close those divs?

Comment: You should check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @Turnip I do close the divs. The HTML is quite long as I am embedding 3 photos from Instagram (each code is long). I've updated the post above. I have tried every combination of CSS I could find on Google--something similar to this:
@media(min-width:768px){
        div {
            float:left;
            width:30%;
    margin-right:5px;
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

You need to use media queries in your css to produce responsive layouts. It can't be done using inline styles.

At a minimum, and from a mobile first approach:

```
<div>
SOURCE 1
</div>
<div>
SOURCE 2
</div>
<div>
SOURCE 3
</div>

<style>
    @media(min-width:768px){
        div {
            float:left;
            width:30%;
    margin-right:5px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Here you have three stacked, full width `divs`. Once the browser or device is equal to or beyond the defined breakpoint of `768px`, the new css takes effect to produce three side-by-side `divs` as defined in the css.

Comment: thank you so much for the CSS. I've tried it and it doesn't stack on mobile. Additionally, it made my desktop view extremely narrow. Hmmm

Comment: @DanielleMarkley You need to remove your inline styles. Additionally you should use class names on your divs and reference those in your css.

Answer (score 1):

See example. You should use percentage dimensions

```css
.col{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 960px){
  .col{
    float:left;
    width: 30%
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
  .col:last-child{
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block{     text-align: center; width:30%; margin:0px; padding:50px 0; float:left;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.block{ width:100%;}
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="block" style="    background: #f00;">
SOURCE 1
</div>
<div class="block" style="    background: #ccc;">
SOURCE 2
</div>
<div class="block" style="    background: #444;">
SOURCE 3
</div>
```

Please check hope so this will help full for you

Answer (score 0):

There is different options to do that, but both use media queries.

You can either put each div on `display: inline-block` on desktop and change them to `display: block` on mobile. Maybe set a `width: 33%` for each div (otherwise if your div are too long they won't be side by side).

Or the other solution:
Put your parent element on `display: flex` on desktop and put it back on `display: block` on mobile.

```css
.sub { background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.6); box-sizing: border-box; border-right: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

.first { display: flex; }
.first .sub { width: 33.3%; }

.second { display: block; margin-top: 20px; }
.second .sub { width: 100%; }

/* media queries for mobile */
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .first { display: block; }
  .first .sub { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="sub">One</div>
  <div class="sub">Two</div>
  <div class="sub">Three</div>
</div>


<div class="second">
  <div class="sub">One</div>
  <div class="sub">Two</div>
  <div class="sub">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `<li>` instead of `<div>`, then use `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;`

Comment: Why would you use `li`?

Comment: @Turnip well cuz it would be easier to work on a group like that

Comment: Regardless if its `<li>` or `<div>`, the CSS you've provided does not change the display between mobile and desktop.  You need a media query.

Comment: @AdamKonieska ofcourse you need a media query, u just use the display:block; at the max width you want